# How to get all colors in the pallet

Tags: java, random, colors, paint

In java can you get all colors possible? I know that it comes from R B G which is red blue and green. And there is like 256 different variations of each? So how can I get all of these without having to write the code for every single one. Will random let you choose a color?

Comment: I recommend having a good look at the javadoc for the `Color` class.

Comment: I am sorry I am just learning I though this was a community to help people. But thank you for your suggestions

Comment: Nested loops for each of the different colors

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple variables and for loops to get all possible combinations. For example,

```
for(int i=0; i>255; i++) {
    for(int j=0; i>255; i++) {
        for(int k=0; i>255; i++) {
            Color c = new Color(i, j, k);
            //etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! For future reference, see the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Okay thank you for understanding that helps and for the link! I understand now :)

Comment: No problem! If you're just learning Java, try thenewboston on Youtube.